# Calculating Greeks for basket option

Tags: greeks

I am stuck with obtaining nice relative error of my analytical derivative of a function. I am comparing values of my function at points $x$ and $x+ \delta$ and the difference does not coincide with derivative value at $x$ multiplied by $\delta$.
I want to calculate derivative of $C$ wrt to $\sigma_i$. 
Maybe I forgot calculus or I am doing silly mistake somewhere and after 10th revision of formula I can not see it. Can you please shed a light on my problem, cause I am crying on it not the first day.

I have such functions, dependencies: $t$ - independent variable,
$$C = C(F,K,\sigma,t)$$
$$F = F(w_i,F_i)$$ 
$$K = K(w_i,K_i)$$
$$ \sigma = \sigma( w_i,\sigma_i,F_i,t)$$
$$F_i = F_i( S_i, R_i, \rho_{xi},\sigma_{x},\sigma_i)$$
$S_i,R_i,\rho_{xi},\sigma_x,\sigma_i,w_i,K_i$ - as well independent variables.

Am I right that total derivative:
$$\frac{dC}{d\sigma_i} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial F}\frac{d F}{d \sigma_i}  + \frac{\partial C}{\partial K}\frac{d K}{d \sigma_i}  +\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}\frac{d \sigma}{d \sigma_i}  +\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} \frac{d t}{d \sigma_i}$$
hence:
$$\frac{dC}{d\sigma_i} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial F} (\frac{\partial F}{\partial w_i}\frac{d w_i}{d \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i}) + 0 + \frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}(\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial w_i}\frac{d w_i}{d \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma_i}\frac{d \sigma_i}{d \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}\frac{d t}{d \sigma_i} ) + 0 $$
$$\frac{dC}{d\sigma_i} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial F} (0 + \frac{\partial F}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i}) + 0 + \frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}( 0  + \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i} + 0) + 0 $$
Have I omitten something?
$$\frac{dC}{d\sigma_i} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial F} \frac{\partial F}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma_i} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i} $$

---

**Update:**

1. Is it a correct way to compute vega wrt to one of the assets in my basket :$\frac{dC}{d\sigma_i} $? I am askying so as I know that partial derivative of $C$ wrt to $\sigma$ is a vega.
2. Interesting, but if I put last summand, i.e. $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial F_i}\frac{d F_i}{d \sigma_i} $ to $0$ then I get **perfect relative error**.

But I am lost, because apparently it is not $0$.

Comment: Have you forgotten a parenthesis in the last line? If yes, then your development seems fine to me. Maybe your error is at another level e.g. when writing the various atomic dependencies? Instead of directly checking $dC/d\sigma_i$, try to check the computation of the other individual gradients to isolate the problem?

Comment: @Quantuple, you are right! To add, I use ready, "in the box" $\frac{\partial C}{\partial F}$, $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}$ which must be correct. Therefore, the only places I can make a mistake are $\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma_i}$, and others.. I will check them separately. Thx !